# Is there any way to display upto 100% in Excel graph?

Tags: excel

Excel percentage graph only showing 0 to 60%. I want make it to show up to 100%

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Good Day,

try this:

1. Click on the vertical axis to select it
2. Right Click the vertical axis and select "Format Axis"
3. Click on the last item to the right with chart icon (upper red box)
4. Change 0.6 to 1.0
   [image]

Comment: Thank you it worked. Good day 